# Failed to show the preferences dialog GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown

Tags: linux, command-line, kali-linux, startup, panel

I'm encountering issue with USB Live persistence Kali linux.
I've installed it correctly and everything works fine initially. But after running it, the upper panel sometimes disappears. When opening the panel from `Application->Setting->Panel`, I encounter the following error:

```
Failed to show the preferences dialog
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown:
The name org.xfce.Panel was not provided by any .service files
```

Comment: can you try this one? if not, it will help you. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=34iXHWuhsss

Answer (score -1):

run this in your terminal, if your panel broken

```
xfce4-panel --disable-wm-check
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).